# PHP OOP User class

Tags: php, oop

I'm currently writing a complete application. Of course, one of the most important functions is the user managament. I have thought this out compltly, but I'm still not sure on one topic.

**What should a user class contain and what not?**

It seems logic that I save at least the user_id and the username in the User object. Due, I will need this very often. But what about information like e-mail, adress, real name, ... Would you place this information as well in the User object?

I was thinking to do it as following:
I save the user_id and username in the object itself, so I could access it with methods liek getUserId() and getUsername(). This methods, surprise surprise, will return $this->userId and $this->username.

About the other information, like adress, I was thinking to add also methods. But I won't store this information in a instance variable. Like the method getAddress() would make a call to the UserMapper, where I would also create a method to get the adress.

```
<?php
//UserMapper
public function getAdress() {
 $this->database->query('SELECT adress FROM users WHERE user_id = ?', array($this->getUserId));
 return $database('adress');
}

//User
public function getAdress() {
 return $this->userMapper->getAdress();
}
?>
```

Or should I create another class for this information?

Comment: Is there a rationale behind *not* simply storing it in the user class?

Comment: It depends on your application. If you have several user types that have different information, create one base class for users (that will contain `user_id` and all other basic info and/or methods) than create another classes for each role that will be derived from base class.

Comment: wouldn't getUserDetails('address'); be a better method than creating individual functions or just getUser() which will return an array of all info?

Comment: That's not very object oriented, Waygood.

Comment: @deceze Yes, the user object will be serialized and stored in a session. It's important to reduce the size of the object.

Comment: @PLB That's unpossible in my 'plan'. I want to create a flexible permission system, so the admin can create multiple groups and chose wich rights they have.

Comment: @Waygood getUserDetails could be a solution, but I'd rather to create all kind of different methods, due it's more OO. Mu UserMapper won't be OO if I implementate it like you say. And returning an array is absolutly not what I want. That's just the reason why I want to create seperate methods, I wan't to reduce the information.

Comment: @WriteDown Hmm, you might want to separate those concerns. Model the `User`/`Person`/whatever *business model class* however it makes the most sense. It's your model layer and should first and foremost express your core application logic. Sessions are a concern of the controller/frontend layer and should be implemented and optimized independently of your business logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to make a distinction between a user and a person.

A person has a name, address, DOB , other facts about him.
A user has credentials, secret question, system rights, etc.

Now, asking yourself what is the relationship between a user and person. 
As Brian above answered it is a good idea to separate the two into different classes and tables by default, because that will make it easier down the road.

Here are some reasoning to break these out.

1. A user will likely remain the same throughout it's existence, the person attached to the user may not be.
2. The information about the person is rarely needed in the context of permissions and roles, so that is extra data that will be floating around in your user class unnecessarily.
   This list goes on...

I generally break out the user stuff into the following classes

```
   User (
        id
        login
        password
        password_expiredate
        enabled
        otherflags
        ) //(occasionally email, if it is used as login)

   Person (
        pid     // If it is not one to one between user and person
        user_id FK
        Name
        DOB
        Email 
        other relevant information
       )
   Address
       ( 
       person_pid
       type //home,work, etc
       Street
       City
       State
       Zip
       Country
       )
   Phone
      (
       person_pid
       type
       number
      )
```

As for creating the classes, in general, I am not sure if it is good practice, but I allow the user to contain a person, which in turn contains the Address and Phone classes with the respective functions.

In my experience, the normalization of the structure allow for flexible development of business rules that will use people and users.

In addition, a person does not have to be a user.

Comment: Thanks for the nice post!

Indeed, it is a nice idea to splits up in multiplce classes. But I think I won't create that much classes as you do. 

My aim is creating a CMS, so the information (like address) isn't that important. It probally will be used only on one page. So I'm not sure if it is intersting to split it up this far.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts...

You might have users of your system, and you might have administrative credentials distinct from any user.  I tend to avoid using "user" for the name of such a class, and often prefer something more like "login" and/or "credential."

You might have multiple types of credentials, ... in addition to username/password, you might also have credentials like oauth, openid, etc.  Typically, a "username" will be an email address.

There may already be libraries to handle what you want to do.

I would probably store a user's contact information separate from their login credentials, but it depends on the type of app.. specifically, it depends if there is always going to be one and only one physical address for any given "user."

Once you have some kind of login class, I would tend to have some kind of permission class that joins logins to objects they have permission to view/update.

btw, you spelled address wrong.